# Browser fingerprinting and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, fingerprint

I'm wondering if there is a way to fake your browser fingerprint (can be tested on sites like https://panopticlick.eff.org/) by making the browser (firefox in my case) supply fake data? 
If so i would like to make an extension that does it. Is that possible? 
If it is any suggestions as to how would i go about doing it?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just make an extension that is a proxy and every `http` request that goes out would go through your extension's proxy. Then take the data and manipulate it however you want and forward it to the destination.

Sample http request

```
POST /path-to/page HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

param1=val1&param2=val2
```

Answer (score 0):

The name off the addon that will fulfill your request is *canvas blocker*

Comment: Hi James Peterson! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please will you supply some more detail about this product, as well as (possibly) links and explanation as to why it answers the question. Specifically, how does it allow the browser to fake its fingerprint. Thanks!

Comment: http://kkapsner.github.io/CanvasBlocker/
Thank you.

to download the extension search canvas blocker in browser addons.

Comment: Please will you update your answer with the additional information?