# What is the new firefox fingerprinter feature doing?

Tags: html, firefox, browser, privacy, fingerprinting

Community, Firefox has a new function . Called fingerprinter (settings under privacy).

I know what fingerprinting means. What I like to ask you is: what is Firefox doing exactly when this feature is activated, what data is being changed by this setting?

Because when you do a test on panopticlick.eff.org, in both cases, active/inactive fingerprinter setting, you still get a unique html canvas hash assigned to you.

So, what is firefox exactly "preventing" or "changing" by this fingerprinter setting then?

- And can you give your short opinion: is it better to activate this new fingerprint setting, or not? If you like to be "less" easier identifiable during web surfing? I have read differing opinions. There are those who say if you block fingerprinting you look more "unique", and those who say, If you allow fingerprint, you "less unique" in the masses...

Thanks all!

Comment: Sorry, but this does not belong to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CoderCharmander , why not? there are plenty other similar answered questions... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671022/browser-fingerprinting-and-firefox

where should we ask this question then?

Answer (score 0):

Browser finger printers are a subset of trackers that allow sites to gather a certain amount of information about a visitor’s browser and device, even without the use of a cookies.

Firefox new feature can help you block fingerprinting coming from many ad trackers.

Keep in mind blocking fingerprinting may cause some sites to break or make them look strange, or the layout will be different. It can also slow down your online experience.